# Spread operator ES5 equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Below is the code I am trying to convert to ES5 for IE compatibility.

```
$.when(...requests).then(function(...responses) {
   // More code goes here
}
```

So far I could convert it to the below and it works well, but I still couldn't replace the `then` part.

```
$.when.apply(null, requests).then(function(...responses) {
   // More code goes here
}
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not transpile the code?

Comment: Also, you seem to only be asking about rest parameter syntax: `function(...responses)`. Only `$.when(...requests)` is using spread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```
$.when.apply(null, requests).then(function() {
   var responses = [].concat.apply([], arguments); // Get a standard array from arguments object
   // More code goes here
}
```

As a disclaimer I quote MDN on the use of `arguments`:

> If you're writing ES6 compatible code, then rest parameters should be preferred.

So when you don't have ES6 support (which seems to be your case), then using `arguments` is fine, but otherwise you should use the spread syntax in the function parameter list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work with a little tweak -> `var responses = [].concat(arguments)[0];`.

Comment: Indeed. I corrected this in the answer. It should in fact use `apply`, otherwise there is no conversion to standard Array. But that conversion is optional. If you don't use Array methods like `.forEach`, ...etc, you can just use `responses = arguments` or use `arguments` directly.